# Which overload would match the call when using a ref?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, overloading, vuejs3

I am faced with a TS error I do not understand with the following code:

```js
<script lang="ts">

import {defineComponent, computed, toRef} from 'vue'
import _ from 'lodash'
import {DateTime} from 'luxon'

interface CalendarEvent {
  start: string
  end: string
  name: string
  id: string
  important: boolean
}

function emptyCalendarEvent(): CalendarEvent[] {
  return [{
    start: '',
    end: '',
    name: '',
    id: '',
    important: false
  }]
}

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'GoogleCalendar',
  props: {
    when: {type: String, default: ''},
    data: {type: Array, default: () => emptyCalendarEvent()},
  },
  setup(props) {

    let allEvents = toRef(props, 'data')
    let importantEvents = computed(() => (allEvents.value.filter((x: CalendarEvent) => x.important)))

(...)
```

The full error on the last line is

```
<html>TS2769: No overload matches this call.<br/>Overload 1 of 2, '(predicate: (value: unknown, index: number, array: unknown[]) =&gt; value is unknown, thisArg?: any): unknown[]', gave the following error.<br/>Argument of type '(x: CalendarEvent) =&gt; boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: unknown, index: number, array: unknown[]) =&gt; value is unknown'.<br/>Types of parameters 'x' and 'value' are incompatible.<br/>Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'CalendarEvent'.<br/>Overload 2 of 2, '(predicate: (value: unknown, index: number, array: unknown[]) =&gt; unknown, thisArg?: any): unknown[]', gave the following error.<br/>Argument of type '(x: CalendarEvent) =&gt; boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: unknown, index: number, array: unknown[]) =&gt; unknown'.<br/>Types of parameters 'x' and 'value' are incompatible.<br/>Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'CalendarEvent'.
```

A more readable version is provided in the console:

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(predicate: (value: unknown, index: number, array: unknown[]) => value is unknown, thisArg?: any): unknown[]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(x: CalendarEvent) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: unknown, index: number, array: unknown[]) => value is unknown'.
      Types of parameters 'x' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'CalendarEvent'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(predicate: (value: unknown, index: number, array: unknown[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): unknown[]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(x: CalendarEvent) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: unknown, index: number, array: unknown[]) => unknown'.
      Types of parameters 'x' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'CalendarEvent'.
    61 |     let allEvents = toRef(props, 'data')
    62 |     // let importantEvents = computed(() => filteredEvents.value.filter((x: CalendarEvent) => x.important))
  > 63 |     let importantEvents = computed(() => (allEvents.value.filter((x: CalendarEvent) => x.important)))
       |                                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    64 |
    65 |     function extractTime(what: string) {
    66 |       return DateTime.fromISO(what).toFormat('H:mm')
```

Well, *readable* is an overstatement in my case - would someone be kind enough to explain to me what this error actually means?

I read some other answers, and it usually means that there is a wrong number of arguments to functions. I think, however, that in my case this more has to do with the Vue3 `ref` concept (wildly guessing)

Answer (score 1):

By default `toRef(...)` has a return type `Ref<unknown[]>` which could be cast to `Ref<CalendarEvent[]>` :

```
import {defineComponent, computed, toRef,Ref} from 'vue'
                                       // import the type Ref
....
  setup(props) {

    let allEvents  = toRef(props,'data') as Ref<CalendarEvent[]>

   let importantEvents = computed(() => (allEvents.value.filter((x) => x.important)))
                                                              // the right type is inferred here
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of `Array` props can't be automatically inferred, so `props.data` resolves as type `unknown[]`.

To explicitly type the array, [declare the prop with the `type` property set to `Array` with a type assertion of `PropType<YourArrayType>`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#annotating-props):

```js
import { PropType } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    data: {               
      type: Array as PropType<CalendarEvent[]>,
      default: () => emptyCalendarEvent()
    },
  },
}
```

That enables TypeScript to infer the correct type from `toRef(props, 'data')`.